# Python Installing Modules on Mac OS

Tags: python, pandas, module, pip

I am new to Python and terminal prompts/installs and I keep running into installation errors when trying to install modules like Pandas.

I have successfully installed  "pip install pandas"
I am unable to install this with pip3 however.

```
Collecting pandas
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
```

I have pip3 installed and python3(this comes with mac os).
I do not understand the conflict between the versions. If I install using pip, its only compatible with python2? 
Why wouldnt I be able to install it using pip3 (see error above)?

Am I somehow installing in the wrong directories or not making the correct distinction for python3 and pip3 version compatibility? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: The installation seems to be successful. However `pandas` installed `0.24.2`, the most recent version that supports Python 2.7. In the terminal it makes no sense to type `pandas --version` as `pandas` is not a command your terminal recognizes, it's something `python` recognizes. Type `python` in the terminal to start python running in the terminal. Now that you're in a python environment you can type `import pandas as pd` and then `pd.__version__` will show you it's installed with '0.24.2'.

Comment: Appreciate the info. I was able to get this to work, I was trying to execute with python3. Is there a version compatible with python3? How would I have installed this differently?

Comment: `pip` and `python` clearly refer to the 2.7. If you want Python 3 you need to install it and then ideally you'd refer to them as pip3 and python3. https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html Has a walkthrough for setting it up. If you've already installed python3 in some other way then you'll need to remember how you aliased it and set up the paths.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully you can see through this and understand what I am missing. But the following reveals: 
xx-mac-mini:~ Mariposa$ pip3 --version
pip 7.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
xx-mac-mini:~ Mariposa$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
xx-mac-mini:~ Mariposa$ python3
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: **_DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support_**

Comment: I would really recommend using virtual environments.

Comment: The pandas installation guide says to use "pip install pandas", and it says it supports "Officially Python 3.6.1 and above, 3.7, and 3.8.". How do I use pandas with python3, if it only installs with pip and works with python2?  What am I missing?

Comment: @meganerdblue _How do I use pandas with python3, if it only installs with pip and works with python2?_ That's the classic, extremely annoying issue of referencing the correct Python/pip installation. Using virtual environments can help with that, and mitigate potential problems. I find Anaconda/Conda particularly good if, like me, you absolutely hate having to mess around with your environment.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the comments, `pip` installs modules for python2. Also, you can't run `pandas` as a command on the shell.

`pip3 install pandas` works for me, on python3 (v3.7.4), which was installed directly from a Mac installer package on the [python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/).  No 'environment configuration' was required.

```
>pip3 install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/ba/f97030b7e8ec0a981abdca173de4e727b3a7b4ed5dba492f362ba87d59a2/pandas-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (9.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 9.8MB 2.8MB/s
```

If you've installed python3 using some different method, then you may need to install packages differently or configure your python installation in some way.

Comment: So it should be "that easy", keeping pip with python2, and pip3 with python 3, so why would I be having issues with pip3 though? I have both python3 and pip3 installed, i keep getting "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pandas"

Comment: How did you install python3? Did you install pip3 separately, or not? (I got pip3 as part of the python package.) Maybe reinstall python3.